# All unit tests that are run are exiting with code 0 (0x0) without even hitting breakpoint

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 15.9.The program gets built successfully but every time I right click "debug test" the compiler exits with the message:

> The program '[xxxxx] testhost.x86.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Both debug output screen and test output screen show the message

> VirtualReadOnlyTestDataStore.OperationStateChanged
>   State=TestExecutionFinished, operationInProgress=False
>   TestDiscoveryStats.OperationStateChanged State=TestExecutionFinished,
>   InProgress=False

This message appears even after putting in a function breakpoint. The breakpoint is not hit by the compiler and it exits with the same message.
There seems to be nothing wrong with the code as it works fine on my colleague's laptop. Also, none of the tests in the test explorer show the green tick mark, they all have the blue exclamation mark

I tried changing the test setting>Default processor architecture to x64 (my computer is 64 bit).
I had updated VS to latest version.
Even tried reinstalling Visual Studio and again it shows the same error.

> The thread 0x5aa8 has exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread 0x166c has
>   exited with code 0 (0x0). The program '[13392] testhost.exe' has
>   exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: I would try "Clean Solution" - it sounds like there might be some old build residue confusing the IDE.

Comment: Put the break point earlier in the code.  Try stepping through code with F11

Comment: Yup I tried cleaning and building solution multiple times. Cleans successfully, builds successfully but 'debug test' exits the program with code 0.
I put the breakpoint earlier in the code (in the constructor) but it still shows the same message. If I press F11 it opens the browser and displays "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" and displays the message "The program '[116] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)." in the VS output screen when I close the browser.

Comment: show us some code.

Comment: I am having the same issue: "testhost.x86.exe: Program Trace has exited with code 0 (0x0)." It has been working without any issue. I think this problem started after my Win 10 box updated and rebooted a couple of days ago. I tried: 1) Cleaned solution; 2) Uninstalled MSTest.TestFramework and MSTest.TestAdapter and reinstalled both; 3) Restarted Visual Studio 2017; 4) Restarted my Win 10 box. None of these helped. None of the answers provided here helps. Any idea? Googling doesn't show lots of results, doesn't seem like a wide spread issue. Hmmm.

Comment: I created a single unit test project and created this unit test method. Tried to debug it, but got the same error.
`public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            string ss = "student";
            string ss2 = ss.Substring(0, 3);
            Assert.AreEqual("stu", ss2);
        }
    }`

Answer (score 4):

Had this same "The program '[10444] testhost.x86.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)." error. UT was testing async code and turned out I was missing 'Task' as return value of the test method.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I needed to add a further Nuget package.  I had already added -

- xunit
- xunit.abstractions

What I was missing was -

- xunit.runner.visualstudio

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from :https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9764695d-e222-43dc-a993-209458bb2e83/not-able-to-debug-my-coded-ui-tests-after-updating-visual-studio-enterprise-2017-from-1532-to?forum=vsunittest

Had to set the system environment value:

Variable Name: **UNITTESTEXPLORER_VSINSTALLPATH** (two underscores) 
Variable Value: Visual Studio IDE location [like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a  decorator without `()`, so the solution was fix this and all works fine again:

before:

```cs
[TestCleanup]
```

**after:**

```cs
[TestCleanup()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a file with `[SetUpFixture]`, I had a property that was not initialising correctly.

Since this piece of code worked before hand, I simply added break points on anything that could occur during initialisation or around that time. This means, didn't put break points within the tests, rather than within the `SetUp` or `TearDown` or any properties/constructures within files with `SetUpFixture` - one of those break points was hit and I could debug it

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue in VS2017, but not in VS2019. 
I tried to add UNITTESTEXPLORER_VSINSTALLPATH but not work.
Then I found the solution which works fine in my case: Properties of the Solution --> Configurations Properties --> check BUILD column for the test project.

Comment: all projects are already checked.   Interesting why some are not running